# hapi basic authentication credential is null

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, hapi

I used the `@hapi/basic` plugin and I wrote validate function like the tutorial. It works correctly and I can log in with the correct username and password and also it will return a 401 HTTP error if I send an incorrect username and password. The problem is, I cannot get credentials in the route handler function. it's always null. please help me if you can.

```
        const validateUser = async (
            request: IRequest,
            username: string,
            password: string,
            h: Hapi.ResponseToolkit,
        ) => {
            try {
                const user = await database.manHourUserModel.findOne({ userName: username });
                if (!user || !user.active) {
                    return {
                        isValid: false,
                        credentials: null,
                    };
                }
                const isValid = user.validatePassword(password);
                return { isValid, credentials: user };
            } catch (error) {
                return { isValid: false };
            }
        };
```

I cannot get credential in route handler function:

```
    public async login(request: IRequest, h: Hapi.ResponseToolkit) {
        return request.auth.credentials;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `user` object inside `request.auth` might solve this:

```
        const validateUser = async (
        request: IRequest,
        username: string,
        password: string,
        h: Hapi.ResponseToolkit,
    ) => {
        try {
            const user = await database.manHourUserModel.findOne({ userName: username });
            if (!user || !user.active) {
                return {
                    isValid: false // This is enough to throw 401.
                };
            }
            const isValid = user.validatePassword(password);
            request.auth.credentials = user; // Add manually
            return { isValid };
        } catch (error) {
            return { isValid: false };
        }
    };
```

Note: I'm not sure it's the correct way of doing this, so maybe upgrading `hapi` version or adding credentials object with using `lean()` in `findOne()` query might also fix it.